# How to iterate a list created with SeqIO using re.findall, FASTA-input

Tags: python, regex, biopython, fasta, python-3.12

I have spent way too much time on this now (+10 hours).

Input is a file in fasta-format.
Output should be a text-file containing the gene-ID and the matched patterns (three different patterns)

I wanted to make my own function to avoid writing the same code three times, but I've given up now and just written it three times (and works fine).

Is there a way to use this:
`records = list(SeqIO.parse('mytextfile.fasta', 'fasta'))`
instead of the code that I'm currently using three times (down below) or some other function? It's for a school assignment so it shouldn't be too complicated either but I have to use the Bio and re-module to solve it.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import re

outfile = 'sekvenser.txt'

for seq_record in SeqIO.parse('prot_sequences.fasta', 'fasta'):
    match = re.findall(r'W.P', str(seq_record.seq), re.I)
    if match:       
        with open(outfile, 'a') as f:
            record_string = str(seq_record.id)
            newmatch = str(match)
            result = record_string+'\t'+newmatch
            print(result)
            f.write(result + '\n')
```

I've tried this

```
records = list(SeqIO.parse('prot_sequences.fasta', 'fasta'))
new_list = []
i = r'W.P'

for i in records:
    match = re.findall(i)
    if match:       
        new_list.append(match)

print(new_list)
```

But it only gives me that findall() is missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'.

As I can see it, i is a string (as I made the variable). Obviously I'm doing something wrong. If I try to insert seq_record that I'm using in my other code, it tells me that seq_record isn't defined. I don't understand what I'm supposed to put after the i in the code.

Comment: 'for rec  in records: match = re.findall(i, str(rec.seq)' should do.  Seqrecord is described here  https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.SeqRecord.html#module-Bio.SeqRecord , re.findall https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input `prot_sequences.fasta` :

```
>one
WWWWWWCCCCCPPPPPP
>two
SSSSSSSSRRRRRRRRTTTTWWWWWWDDDDDDMMMMM
>three
QQQQQQQQQWAPTCCCCCCCWYPGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

code :

```
import Bio

from Bio import SeqIO

import re


print('biopython version : ', Bio.__version__)

records = list(SeqIO.parse('prot_sequences.fasta', 'fasta'))
new_list = []
i = r'W.P'

#print(i)

for rec in records:
    
    #print('rec : ', rec, rec.seq , type(rec.seq)
    match = re.findall(i, str(rec.seq) )
    if match:       
        new_list.append(match)

print(new_list)
```

output :

```
biopython version :  your Biopython Version
[['WAP', 'WYP']]
```

if you uncomment : `#print('rec : ', rec, rec.seq , type(rec.seq)`

you'll see that `rec.seq` it's  a `<class 'Bio.Seq.Seq'>` so not suitable as argument to be feed on [re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
records = [str(rec.seq) for rec in SeqIO.parse('prot_sequences.fasta', 'fasta')]

print( records, type(records))
```

does give you a list of string but you will loose the `rec.id` needed for your assignment

See [Bio.SeqIO.parse(handle, format, alphabet=None)](https://biopython.org/docs/latest/api/Bio.SeqIO.html?highlight=seqio#Bio.SeqIO.parse) to get a grasp of the Object properties that:

> Turn a sequence file into an iterator returning SeqRecords.

you could do:

```
records = [[rec.id , re.findall(i, str(rec.seq) , re.I)] for rec in SeqIO.parse('prot_sequences.fasta', 'fasta') if len(re.findall(i, str(rec.seq) , re.I)) >= 1]

print(records)
```

to get :

```
[['three', ['WAP', 'WYP']]]
```

but I am not sure it's the best way to do that:
is actually very difficult to read,
I am not sure is fast because (not sure again but it uses `re.findall` twice see [Does Python automatically optimize/cache function calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51803046/does-python-automatically-optimize-cache-function-calls)); so to get it maybe fastest but even more ugly , use:

```
records = [[rec.id , a] for rec in SeqIO.parse('prot_sequences.fasta', 'fasta') if len(a:= re.findall(i, str(rec.seq) , re.I) ) >= 1]

print(records)
```

out:

```
[['three', ['WAP', 'WYP']]]
```

as per the use of `list()` , the ones below gives same result:

```
records = list([[rec.id , re.findall(i, str(rec.seq) , re.I)] for rec in SeqIO.parse('prot_sequences-2.fasta', 'fasta') if len(re.findall(i, str(rec.seq) , re.I)) >= 1])

print(records)


records = list([rec.id , a] for rec in SeqIO.parse('prot_sequences-2.fasta', 'fasta') if len(a:= re.findall(i, str(rec.seq) , re.I) ) >= 1)

print(records)
```

res:

```
[['three', ['WAP', 'WYP']]]
[['three', ['WAP', 'WYP']]]
```